# Getting element properties from first list item by getting element once vs couple of times performance

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Can't find any article regarding this. Does it have any impact if we use:

```
Fruit fruit = fruits.get(0);

FruitDto dto = new FruitDto();
dto.setPrice(fruit.getPrice());
dto.setType(fruit.getType());
... eg to set 10 properties using fruit.getSomeProperty
```

compared to:

```
FruitDto dto = new FruitDto();
dto.setPrice(fruits.get(0).getPrice());
dto.setType(fruits.get(0).getType());
... eg to set 10 properties using fruits.get(0).getSomeProperty
```

and is there any advantage if we use `fruits.stream().findFirst()` instead of `get(0)`?

Comment: The performance difference might be small but since the first variant is both, more readable and potentially more efficient why not just use it? `fruits.stream().findFirst()` enforces you to deal with the potentially absent value when the list is empty. But when you know that the list is not empty, `get(0)` obviously is simpler. And even `if(!fruits.isEmpty()) { … fruits.get(0) … }` might be simpler than bringing in a Stream operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes some impact, but it might be negligible depending on the collection type and whether you're actually pulling item 0 or some higher index (different collection types have different scaling of `get`, e.g. `get(0)` vs. `get(1000000)` on a LinkedList would be very different in comparative runtimes).

I would also say the first version is preferable from a cleanliness/maintenance POV.  Consider sequential calls to `fruits.get(0).getProperty()` for some set of properties, and then we need to change from the 0th item to the 1st (e.g. need to change to `fruits.get(0).getProperty()` in many spots).  That change now runs a higher risk of some typo leading to a bug (e.g. someone misses changing a 0 to a 1).

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's rather about cleaner code style than about performance, and the first approach may be easily extracted into a mapper method, to copy the properties of an entity into DTO (and it does not actually matter that the entity belongs to some collection at some index):

```java
FruitDto dto = toDto(fruits.get(0));

static FruitDto toDto(Fruit fruit) {
    FruitDto dto = new FruitDto();
    dto.setPrice(fruit.getPrice());
    dto.setType(fruit.getType());
    // ...
    return dto;
}
```

Regarding use of `Stream::findFirst` instead of checking the size/emptiness of the list -- it's also rather about code style and handling the empty input collection:

- "imperative"

```java
if (fruits.isEmpty()) throw new NoFruitException(); // or return "empty" dto

FruitDto dto = toDto(fruits.get(0));
```

- "functional" using `Optional`

```java
FruitDto dto = fruits.stream().findFirst() // Optional<Fruit>
    .map(Mapper::toDto)                    // Optional<FruitDto>
    .orElseThrow(NoFruitException::new);   // or .orElse(EMPTY_DTO)
```

Comment: You can also use `findFirst().orElseThrow(NoFruitException::new).toDto()`

Comment: This implies that `toDto` method is implemented in the entity `Fruit` class. I think it would be rather: `Mapper.toDto(fruits.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(NoFruitException::new))`

Comment: Indeed. For a static method, that ordinary invocation would probably be less readable, unless it’s within the same class. I’m not very used to this concept of having multiple classes for exactly the same thing and needing to copy the properties from one to another…